# octave/matlab - convert string into matrix of unique words

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, octave

In Octave, I want to convert a string into a matrix of strings.  Say I have a string:

```
s = "one two three one one four five two three five four"
```

I want to split it into a matrix so that it looks like:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

With duplicates removed.

This code:

```
words = strsplit(s, ",") %Split the string s using the delimiter ',' and return a cell string array of substrings
```

Just creates a matrix `words` into exactly the same as `s`.

How to I convert my string into a matrix of unique words?

Comment: Your separator should be a space, not a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will also accomplish that:

```
unique(regexp(string, '[A-z]*', 'match'))
```

or, alternatively,

```
unique(regexp(s, '\s', 'split'))
```

Basically the same as Werner's solution, but it saves a temporary and is more flexible when more complicated matches need to be made.

Comment: Thanks, but my script / the console freezes at this line. I'm using Xoctave

Comment: @Obay: well, it works OK on MATLAB...perhaps file a bug report to Octave developers?

Comment: works fine for me in octave 3.6.4, at least for short strings like in the OP's example.

Answer (score 3):

On matlab:

```
string = 'one two three one one four five two three five four'
% Convert it to a cell string:
cell_string = strread(string,'%s');
% Now get the unique values:
unique_strings=unique(cell_string,'stable')
```

If you want char array with the unique values separated with spaces, add the following lines:

```
unique_strings_with_spaces=cellfun(@(input) [input ' '],unique_strings,'UniformOutput',false) % Add a space to each cell
final_unique_string = cell2mat(unique_strings_with_spaces') % Concatenate cells
final_unique_string = final_unique_string(1:end-1) % Remove white space
```

Output:

```
'one two three four five'
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first code snippet produces the error: `error: textread: couldn't open data file one two three one one four five two three five four`

Comment: @Obay sorry for the late answer, try using `textscan` instead. Seems that octave textread doesn't work as matlab's one.

Comment: @Obay It seems there was a small mistake in the first part (`textread` instead of `strread`). Have now fixed this and confirmed that the first solution works on matlab.

Answer (score 2):

words=unique([strsplit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)('one two three one one four five two three five four',' '))

words =

```
'five'    'four'    'one'    'three'    'two'
```