# saving and retrieving string data in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

Hi can any one help me in dealing with strings in MATLAB. For example, the string

```
A = 'A good looking boy'
```

how can we store these individual words in arrays and later retrieve any of the words?

Comment: Related: [octave/matlab - convert string into matrix of unique words](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17576191)

Answer (score 2):

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576191/octave-matlab-convert-string-into-matrix-of-unique-words), you could use

```
>> A = 'A good looking boy';
>> C = regexp(A,'[A-z]*', 'match')
C = 
    'A'    'good'    'looking'    'boy'
```

so that

```
>> C{1}
ans = 
    A

>> C{4}
ans = 
    boy

>> [C{:}]
ans =
    Agoodlookingboy
```

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way would be using `strsplit`

```
C = strsplit(A,' ')
```

However as it is not available in my version I suppose this is only a builtin function in matlab 2013a and above. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html).

If you are using an older version of matlab, you can also choose to get [this File Exchange solution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21710-string-toolkits/content/strings/strsplit.m), which basically does the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple function `textscan` for that:

`C = textscan(A,'%s');`

C will be a cell array. This function is in Matlab at least since R14.